# Cookie based authentication in .NET 6 Core API using Identity

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, cookies, asp.net-identity, .net-6.0

I have created a new .NET Core API project in .NET 6 and implemented Cookie authentication using Identity.

I have created the method below to create cookie

`public async Task GenerateCookieAuthentication(string username)
{
var claims = await GetClaims(username);

```
AuthenticationProperties authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
{
    IsPersistent = true
};

ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

ClaimsPrincipal pricipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

await _httpContext.HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, pricipal, authProperties);
```

}`

I have added configuration in program.cs

`services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{

```
  options.CookieName = "MyCookieName";
  options.Cookie.HttpOnly = false;
   options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
   options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
   options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
   options.SlidingExpiration = true;
```

});`

System create multiple cookies ".AspNetCore.Identity.Application" and my ".MyCookieName" which seems strange to me because it should only create one cookie. There are couple of problems that I have to report

1- Multiple Cookies are being generated

2- If I pass my cookie ".MyCookieName" to be authorized then request is not being authorized because it does not have the claims in it but it works fine with ".AspNetCore.Identity.Application" since it has the claims.

3- I can not change the name of ".AspNetCore.Identity.Application" cookie and the expiration time remains 14 days

4- API returns 404 in case if request is not authorized but it should return 401

Please review this and provide your feedback just to see where I am doing things wrong.

Best,
Sohaib

Expected Behavior
1- One cookie should be created with proper name, expiration time and claims in it which can be authorized properly.
2- API should return 401 instead of 404 when request is not authorized.

Comment: I didn't generate 2 cookie with your code. Could you post the whole program.cs?

Comment: if the claimsprincipal user object is too large, then it will create multiple cookies, because one cookie can max be aound 4kb, that part is totally normal. Please show more code for the 404 and 401 issue,

Comment: I have followed this code example to generate cookie